# How to reduce overdraw in lazy layouts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I noticed a lot of overdraw in my resuable layout despite making my `LazyColumn` and `LazyRow` components reusable. Considering the attched screenshot, how can this overdraw be reduced? Especially for the red parts?

[image]

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NestedScrollingTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MyScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldTitle: String, scaffoldFab: @Composable () -> Unit,
                       scaffoldContent: @Composable (contentPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = scaffoldTitle)
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            scaffoldFab
        },
        content = { contentPadding ->
            scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyRow(lazyRowItems: Array<T>,
                        lazyRowItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
                        onClickLazyRowItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues()
    ) {
        items(lazyRowItems) { itemR ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onClickLazyRowItem(itemR)
                }) {
                lazyRowItemLayout(itemR)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyColumn(
    header: @Composable () -> Unit,
    lazyColumnItems: Array<T>,
    lazyColumnItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
    onClickLazyColumnItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 80.dp)
        ) {
            item { header.invoke() }
            item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp)) }
            items(lazyColumnItems) { itemC ->
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        onClickLazyColumnItem(itemC)
                    }) {
                    lazyColumnItemLayout(itemC)
                }

                // Show horizontal line between items
                Divider(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
            }
        }

        ButtonScrollToTopList(listState = listState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ButtonScrollToTopList(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    listState : LazyListState
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val showButton by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showButton, enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut(),
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(bottom = 50.dp), Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp),
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        listState.animateScrollToItem(index = 0)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.VerticalAlignTop,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
                Text(stringResource(id = R.string.back_to_top))
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    MyReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "Demo",
        scaffoldFab = { /*TODO*/ },
        scaffoldContent = {
            MyScreenContent(contentPadding = it)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)
    ) {
        Column(content = {
                ReusableLazyColumn(
                    header = {
                        ReusableLazyRow(
                            lazyRowItems = rowItems,
                            lazyRowItemLayout = {
                                OutlinedCard(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .height(350.dp)
                                        .padding(16.dp),
                                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
                                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                                    containerColor = Color.Unspecified
                                ) {
                                    Column {
                                        Box(
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .background(Color.LightGray)
                                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                                .height(30.dp)
                                        )
                                        Text(
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                                            text = it.rowItemTitle
                                        )

                                        Text(
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                                            text = it.rowItemDesc,
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            onClickLazyRowItem = { listenerRowItems }
                        )
                    },
                    lazyColumnItems = columnItems,
                    lazyColumnItemLayout = {
                        Row {
                            Text(
                                text = it.columnItemTitle,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(16.dp)
                                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            )
                        }
                    },

                    onClickLazyColumnItem = { listenerColumnItems }
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```